# Using regex, replace any line within a block of text that starts with "embed:"

Tags: php, regex, string

As the title says, I am looking for a regex, using php code, that given a $string with line breaks such as the following:

```
Hello my name is John Doe. Here is a cool video:

embed:http://youtube.com/watch......

I hope you liked it!
```

It would return:

```
Hello my name is John Doe. Here is a cool video:

I hope you liked it!
```

Comment: From embed until the end of the line?

Comment: @jack to the end of the line, not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
preg_replace('/^embed:.*\s*/m', '', $block_of_text);
```

Explanation:

1. The `/m` modifier enabled multi-line mode (so you can easily match line-based patterns)
2. It matches the start of the line using the caret symbol (anchor): `^`
3. Matches the `"embed:` string
4. Matches until the end of the line using `.*`
5. Matches any newlines and white spaces after the current line (this cleans up the empty lines better)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
preg_replace('#embed:.*?\n*#m', '', $string);
```